# Export attribute on overriden method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, foundation

I am using a binding library around objective c code.

Method generated by Sharpie created the following code:

```
// -(BOOL)shouldRenderAsCluster:(id<GMUCluster> _Nonnull)cluster atZoom:(float)zoom;
[Export("shouldRenderAsCluster:atZoom:")]
bool ShouldRenderAsCluster(ICluster cluster, float zoom);
```

I created a class (inheriting from the above library) that overrides this method.

Do I need to place the Export attribute on my code as well?

Comment: Its easy to try it both with and without, right? What happens when you do so? Be bold! Try things, test the result.

Comment: Well, it actually works even without the attribute on the overridden method. I was just wondering if there are situations when it is not being called, due to reasons?